# CSS to detect if an element is close to the edge of the screen

Tags: html, css, position

Is there a way I can write CSS that targets when an element is close to the edge of the screen? If I style up a tooltip to appear to the right but if the trigger element is x pixels near the right hand side of the screen then make the tooltip appear on the left instead.

I know I could write some script but I am wondering if I can do it with pure CSS like a media query for an element's position on screen.

```css
a.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

a.tooltip >div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin-right: -350px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding 5px;
}

a.tooltip:focus >div,
a.tooltip:hover >div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 450px;">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip">
     Keyword
     <div>
       This text is fine to appear on the right as it doesn't run off the screen
     </div>
   </a>
 </div>
 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip">
  Keyword
  <div>
    I would like to make this text appear on the left as it runs off the screen
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: No there is not, you require javascript

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you would need to add JavaScript.

I'm not sure what the context or use case is for this. But using a media query would achieve a similar outcome, as the only way that an element would get X pixels from the side of the screen width would be resizing no?

Edit:

```css
a.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

a.tooltip >div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-right: -350px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding 5px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:530px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  #righty{
        left:-350px;
  }
}

a.tooltip:focus >div,
a.tooltip:hover >div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 450px;">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip">
     Keyword
     <div>
       This text is fine to appear on the right as it doesn't run off the screen
     </div>
   </a>
 </div>
 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip">
  Keyword
  <div id="righty">
    I would like to make this text appear on the left as it runs off the screen
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Did you even run my snippet?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. See edit. Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't use a class as the text comes from a database so don't know which ones will overflow.